# change event not stopping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change Country event when (ddlcountry) select value but the change event fire continuously.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlCountry').on('change', function () {
        if ($('#ddlCountry option:selected').index() > 0) {
            getStateDetails();
        }
    });
    $('#ddlState').on('change', function () {                
        if ($('#ddlState option:selected').index() > 0) {
            getCityDetails();
        }
    });
});

$('#ddlCountry').val(data.CountryID).trigger('change');
$('#ddlState').val(data.StateID).trigger('change');
```

How can I stop this.

Comment: Can you post code of these two functions : `getStateDetails` and `getCityDetails`

Comment: Also why aren't your calls to .val & .trigger in the ready block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would be getting data variable's value in `getStateDetails` and `getCityDetails` functions, and so following two lines are getting new values each time:

```
$('#ddlCountry').val(data.CountryID).trigger('change');
$('#ddlState').val(data.StateID).trigger('change');
```

And they trigger `change` event then. And again when you really select any value from these dropdown, the jquery change event triggers and calls those above mentioned functions and then the cycle goes on and on.

To pass value of selected option of dropdowns you can code like this:

```
$('#ddlCountry').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#ddlCountry option:selected').index() > 0) {
        getStateDetails($(this).val());
    }
});
$('#ddlState').on('change', function () {                
    if ($('#ddlState option:selected').index() > 0) {
        getCityDetails($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Pass their value as an argument in the functions.

Comment: Checking it JSfiddle now.

Comment: Remove these two lines and recurring events will be stopped.
$('#ddlCountry').val(data.CountryID).trigger('change');
$('#ddlState').val(data.StateID).trigger('change');

Comment: if I remove these two lines so how can I select drop-down by value. tell me fast it's urgent

Comment: Your welcome bro, can you please accept my answer and give an up vote please ?

Comment: Ha ha ha ha. yes bro

Answer (score 0):

Generally while continiously triggering events we can use following to avoid it:

1. Use off() and on() in a single statement(i.e
   .off().on(function(){})).
2. Moving the Javascript or Jquery code to
   other js file.

Hope this helps!